# Why doesn't the Ansible copy module copy this dir?

Tags: ansible

This should be easy, but I've been trying for an hour. My code gets Ansible to copy `.vimrc` to each host, but `.vim` is silently ignored.

```
---
- name: vim pkg
  apt: pkg=vim state=installed

- name: vim dirs
  file: path=/home/jefdaj/.vim state=directory
  file: path=/root/.vim        state=directory

- name: vim files

  # these work
  copy: src=vim/vimrc dest=/home/jefdaj/.vimrc force=yes
  copy: src=vim/vimrc dest=/root/.vimrc        force=yes

  # but these don't
  copy: src=vim/bundle dest=/home/jefdaj/.vim/bundle force=yes recurse=yes
  copy: src=vim/bundle dest=/root/.vim/bundle        force=yes recurse=yes
```

What's up with that?
I've tried lots variations on the paths.
It happens in ansible 1.5.5 on Debian, and also on the current git version.

EDIT: Now it tries to copy, but always fails while creating one of the many dirs with an error like `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.vim/bundle/bundle/vim-easymotion/autoload/vital/Over'`

Comment: So are you saying that the problem is this section? `copy: src=vim/vim/bundle dest=/home/jefdaj/.vim/` If not, please clarify.

Comment: I think so. I just put the rest because I wasn't sure.

Comment: OK I'm a little more familiar with Ansible now. Simplified the question.

Comment: It is really amazing how bad `copy` is compared to `synchronize`.  For bulk copies the difference is orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why `copy` fails, but the solution was to use `synchronize` instead. This works:

```
- name: vim files
  synchronize:
    src=/absolute/repo/path/roles/common/files/{{ item.src }}
    dest={{ item.dst }}
  with_items:
    - {src: vim/bundle, dst: /home/jefdaj/.vim  }
    - {src: vim/vimrc , dst: /home/jefdaj/.vimrc}
    - {src: vim/bundle, dst: /root/.vim         }
    - {src: vim/vimrc , dst: /root/.vimrc       }

- name: vim permissions
  file: path={{ item.pth }} owner={{ item.own }} group={{ item.grp }} recurse=yes
  with_items:
    - {pth: /root/.vim         , own: root  , grp: root  }
    - {pth: /root/.vimrc       , own: root  , grp: root  }
    - {pth: /home/jefdaj/.vim  , own: jefdaj, grp: jefdaj}
    - {pth: /home/jefdaj/.vimrc, own: jefdaj, grp: jefdaj}
```

I had to hardcode the base path because it doesn't seem to handle relative ones properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `file` and `copy` tasks is that there are multiple actions in a task. An Ansible task can have only one action.

Change your play as follows and it should work:

```
---
- name: vim pkg
  apt: pkg=vim state=installed

- name: vim dir for jefdaj
  file: path=/home/jefdaj/.vim state=directory

- name: vim dir for root
  file: path=/root/.vim        state=directory

...
```

The same applies to "vim files" tasks: split them into four tasks.